# 3D-transforms, z-index and Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transforms

I know 3d-transforms and z-indexes don't work especially well together, but I'm having this issue (only in Safari) for which I'm hoping there's still a solution.

Basically, I have 2 elements on top of each other. The one in the "back" (with the lower z-index) is being rotated in 3d space. I would still however like the top element to be on top at all times.

```css
.button {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.button:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: red;
    transition: transform .2s;
}
.button:hover:after {
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

This works well in Chrome and Firefox (haven't tested IE yet), but in Safari the back element "cuts through" the top element, making half of the top element invisible.

I've tried setting `transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` to the top element and also `transform-style:preserve-3d` to the parent element, with no success.

I've seen other posts about this on here, but they all seem to be outdated and the solutions don't seem to work.

You can see a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6mtgts33/

Answer (score 1):

Add following:

```
.button span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6mtgts33/2/

```css
.button { padding:10px 30px; position:relative; display:inline-block; color:white; cursor:pointer; }
.button span { position:relative; display: inline-block; transform: translateZ(100px); z-index: 2; }
.button:after { content:""; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:10px; background:red; transition:transform .2s; }

.button:hover:after { transform:rotateY(30deg); }
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Actually you don't need `z-index: 2` for Safari, but need it for Chrome still.
Haven't checked in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
transform: rotateY(30deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);  //chrome and safari
```